# Outlook get warned before deleting messages from Outlook's explorer pane

Tags: vba, email, outlook, confirmation

This post first part is an answer to a question I couldn't find an answer to, while the second part is a remaining question on the topic.

Basically I tend to accidentally delete Outlook mails, sometimes even without noticing and therefore wanted a confirmation.
There is a solution for this when deleting an email opened in a separate window:
https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/get-warned-moving-deleting-items-outlook/    (Many thanks to that author btw)
but this solution does not cover the case of deleting an email from within Outlook's explorer pane.
This post gave a hint but not an answer
https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/get-warned-moving-non-empty-folder-outlook/

So the solution is (much of the code taken from the posts referenced above):

```
Private WithEvents objExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Private WithEvents objCurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objExplorer = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub objExplorer_Activate()
    'Get the currently selected folder
    Set objCurrentFolder = objExplorer.CurrentFolder
End Sub

Private Sub objCurrentFolder_BeforeItemMove(ByVal Item As Object, ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim xPrompt As String
  Dim xYesOrNo As Integer
  xPrompt = "Delete?"
  xYesOrNo = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Confirm Deleting Mail")
  If xYesOrNo = vbYes Then
    Cancel = False
  Else
    Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub
```

**Remaining question**
The annoying thing with the above code is that when deleting a selection of multiple emails, the confirmation request is issued for each email, which is quite a drag when deleting 10+ emails.
So far I've failed to come up with a proper, i.e. robustly coded solution for this (tried the selection approach – see the update below).
→ Any ideas?

### Update 2020-June-08 – Quasi solution

By now I've got what I'd call a quasi solution covering all tricky cases encountered so far including events caused by undo, moving emails, opening an email in a separate window and then deleting, …
The trouble is that I now have got one flag (true/false) like variable and a counter which have to be updated each time one of the above events is fired. Result: Difficult to overview spaghetti like code

→ I can post the code in case someone's interested, but be aware that it is not nice and short.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is how to avoid multiple prompts? Off the top of my head:
1. On the first prompt, check the number of selected items (`Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count`), store in a separate variable and skip that many future prompts by decrementing the counter each time the event handler fires  and prompting only when it reaches 0).
2. Check the time when the prompt was displayed, and avoid showing future prompts for another, say, 3 seconds.

Comment: Many thanks!
I've already tried Selection.Count approaches, but this can go seriously wrong when objCurrentFolder_BeforeItemMove was previously triggered by a different event such as objMail_BeforeDelete or when triggering an undo.

Basically the variable storing the amount of prompts to skip ends up being out of sync.

Comment: Then you can use a timestamp.

Comment: While not perfect I now agree that the timestamp approach has the potential to make the code much easier to follow.
→ I'll try it this week end.
Thank you!