# Outlook - Move any email deleted from certain folders to a subfolder of Deleted Items instead

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a client that would like any email deleted from within certain folders in Outlook to go into a sub-folder of her Deleted Items automatically. There are 3 different folders she would like this to happen for, all are sub-folders of her Inbox.

I am mildly VBA savvy, meaning I can usually hack something together from similar code to make it fit what I am trying to accomplish, but I have not been able to find anything close enough to what she is asking for that I could modify to fit this need.

Any tips would be appreciated.

*Edit:*

Adding the code I used in case someone else could benefit from it:

```
Dim WithEvents olFolder1 As Outlook.Folder
Dim WithEvents olFolder2 As Outlook.Folder
Dim WithEvents olFolder3 As Outlook.Folder
Dim olDelFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.Folder

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set olFolder1 = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder1 = olFolder1.Folders("Subfolder of Inbox Name")
Set olFolder1 = olFolder1.Folders("Subfolder of Subfolder Name")
Set olFolder2 = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder2 = olFolder2.Folders("Subfolder of Inbox Name")
Set olFolder2 = olFolder2.Folders("Subfolder of Subfolder Name")
Set olFolder3 = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder3 = olFolder3.Folders("Subfolder of Inbox Name")
Set olFolder3 = olFolder3.Folders("Subfolder of Subfolder Name")
Set olDelFolder =  Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
Set olDestFolder = olDelFolder.Folders("Subfolder of Deleted Items Name")
End Sub

Private Sub olFolder1_BeforeItemMove(ByVal Item As Object, ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, Cancel As Boolean)
If MoveTo = olDelFolder Then
Cancel = True
Item.Move olDestFolder
Else
Cancel = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub olFolder2_BeforeItemMove(ByVal Item As Object, ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, Cancel As Boolean)
If MoveTo = olDelFolder Then
Cancel = True
Item.Move olDestFolder
Else
Cancel = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub olFolder3_BeforeItemMove(ByVal Item As Object, ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, Cancel As Boolean)
If MoveTo = olDelFolder Then
Cancel = True
Item.Move olDestFolder
Else
Cancel = False
End If
End Sub
```

*Note:*

If a message is manually moved to the Deleted Items folder instead of being deleted in a traditional way, a copy of the message ends up in both the Deleted Items and the specified Sub-folder. Not sure why that is, but the end user won't be manually moving messages like that so it wasn't something I needed to fix.

Comment: Try verifying the parent of the item then change to a move. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234357/outlook-get-warned-before-deleting-messages-from-outlooks-explorer-pane and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046741/outlook-vba-beforedelete-not-working

Comment: Do not compare two `MAPIFolder` objects. use `Namespace.CompareEntryIDs` and pass the folder entry ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Folder.BeforeItemMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.beforeitemmove) event which is fired when an item is about to be moved or deleted from a folder, either as a result of user action or through program code. The second parameter represents the folder to which the item is being moved. So, you can check whether it is `Deleted Folder` or not. If so, you may cancel the default action by setting the third parameter to true. Set the `Cancel` parameter to `true to cancel the move or delete action. Then you may programmatically [move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) the item to the required destination instead.

Comment: This answer gave me a jumping off point from which I was able to build a working solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CrystalO. If you post your solution others may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Deleted Items folder. Unlike the  `Folder.BeforeItemMove` event (which is UI specific and does not fire in all cases), `Items.ItemAdd` event is much more reliable.

Comment: It may be more reliable (I can't comment on that since I don't know for certain), but the only deciding factor to which messages need to be moved is the folder the messages originated from. I was unable to discover a property to filter for when monitoring Deleted Items for new messages that could distinguish the originating folder. I'm not saying there isn't one and please correct me if I am mistaken.